In Apache/Passenger configuration on RH8.10, why is /tmp/passenger.spawn.XXX not created?
I am running Passenger 6.0.23 on RH8.10.  The passenger log includes:
[ D 2024-08-07 10:04:43.3760 196318/Tk LveLoggingDecorator.h:67 ]: LVE not in [pid 196318, uid 99, min_uid 500]
[ D 2024-08-07 10:04:43.3765 196318/Tk age/Cor/Spa/SmartSpawner.h:424 ]: Preloader process forked for appRoot=/hwnet/verifweb/prod/current: PID 196572
App 196572 output: [ D 2024-08-07 10:04:43.3990 196572/T1 age/Spa/SpawnEnvSetupperMain.cpp:768 ]: shellName = 'nologin' detected as supporting '-l': false
App 196572 output: Error: Unable to execute command '/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/passenger-6.0.23/buildout/support-binaries/PassengerAgent spawn-env-setupper /tmp/passenger.spawn.XXXXKNz7CL --after': Permission denied (errno=13)```

**I suspect the reason for this failure is that (in this case) /tmp/passenger.spawn.XXXXKNz7CL does not exist.**

I do not know when the /tmp/passenger.spawn.XXX directory is supposed to be created.   If I manually create it (and its subdirectories) they are then populated with some sensible-looking files

I have checked to confirm that selinux is not running.
I have tried restarting httpd, but always see an analogous message in the passenger log.

I note that passenger core is running as root, and that root can write in /tmp.


Having dug through the code, I'mpretty sure that that the important line of the log is:
shellName = 'nologin' detected as supporting '-l': false    So now I have to figure out why it's running with a shell marked nologin

I changed the shell (in /etc/passwd) of nobody to /binbash.   This got me past the first problem, but now I get another that I do not understand:
SpawnEnvSetupperShell: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/passenger-6.0.23/buildout/support-binaries/PassengerAgent: Permission denied
SpawnEnvSetupperShell: line 0: exec: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/passenger-6.0.23/buildout/support-binaries/PassengerAgent: cannot execute: Permission denied```
This is curious as permission is 755


Here is how I resolved this:

I determined (from the detailed debug infomation provided by Passenger) that the process was running as 'nobody', and therefore had a default" shell of "/sbin/nologin".   I changed (in /etc/passwd) the default shell to "/bin/bash".
This allowed significant progress, but then reported file access problems to modules in the Passenger installation.  While these files were executable by everyone, directories in their path were not readable by nobody.  I updated the permissions of all passenger directories in /usr/local/lib/ruby hierarchy to allow read access by 'other'.

This has allowed passenger to serve my sinatra application successfully.
